# What happened to the plain-text alternative in newsletters?

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

I used to read Stack Exchange newsletters in mutt all the time, but now I'm just presented with this:

```
Date: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 18:01:44 +0000 (UTC)
From: Stack Overflow <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>
To: «redacted»
Subject: Meta Stack Exchange Newsletter - Thursday, January 25, 2018
⋮

[-- text/html is unsupported (use 'v' to view this part) --]
```

instead of the Markdown that it used to show. It appears the newsletters are now HTML-only and omit the plain text alternative. It used to be easy to select the link in Mutt and middle-click it into Firefox. Viewing the HTML as text doesn't really work as an alternative; it is *much* less readable than the Markdown version, especially with the 9-line-long links!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that was an oversight... We recently moved newsletters from being sent / managed by stackexchange.com into the main Q&A network sites. The original code had no explicit step to generate plain text so it got missed when moving things over.

We now have an explicit template for doing so and I've just pushed that to prod. Any emails you receive subsequently will now have a decent text-only version as well.

Thanks for the feedback!